# how to bootstrap a grails plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, bootstrapping

I am using grails 1.3.7 to create a grails plugin. So I've created the plugin but the thing is that grails doesn't generate a Bootstrap.groovy class for the plugin. For normal projects it's generated, but not for plugin projects. I've read on random forums that this is a new 'feature' since grails 1.3.x.
My question is, is there a way to bootstrap a plugin (using grails 1.3.7) and if so, how would one do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2994379/6509 -- top result if you search for `[grails] bootstrap plugin`

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have tried that option but grails doesn't recognize my 'custom' bootstrap class. There must be a place to configure grails so that a cutom bootstrap class is used.

Comment: Oh and by the way, the answer in that post isn't correct. The name of the boostrap class should be BootStrap.groovy not changed to MyPluginBootStrap.groovy. It works now, I made the mistake of calling it Bootstrap.groovy instead of BootStrap.groovy......

Comment: Fair enough, I hadn't tried it, I linked to it as I thought it might help you...  :-/

Comment: Actually, the answer in that post is accurate.  I currently have a grails 1.3.7 project that uses 5 different modules packaged as plugins.  2 of them have their own boot strap named according to Burt's answer in that other post.

Comment: Could you then please tell me how to configure my projects so that a custom bootstrap class is used? Just giving it a custom name doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your src/GrailsPlugin.groovy file.