# Is it possible to disable the BootStrap of a grails plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-plugin

In this post, it's described how to enable the BootStrap of a grails plugin: [Is there an equivalent to the Bootstrap class in a Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994379/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-bootstrap-class-in-a-plugin).

If a 3rd party plugin has a BootStrap included in this way, is it possible to forcibly *exclude* `MyPluginBootStrap`, or at least prevent its execution?

Answer (score 1):

Very straightforward solution - override it by creating bootstrap file with the same name in application (MyPluginBootStrap.grotovy in your case).

Comment: Almost seems to be a race as to which one is called first.